# Make a JSON file with lists in it

Tags: python, json, list

How can I create a JSON file with a given amount of lists in it using Python? So lets say `100`

```json
{
    "100": [

    ],

    "99": [

    ],

    "98": [

    ],

    "97": [

    ],

    "96": [
        
    ]
}
```

All the way down to 1

Comment: Please post your attempted solution - something we can debug. Start by creating a python dictionary of lists. Then use the json module to write the file.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes but that's why I asked the question. It's ridiculous to make a dictionary of 100 lists to write to the JSON file right?

Comment: So what have you tried? What do you have problem with - loop over range of numbers, createing list, creating dict, dump to json? Did you do any research?

Comment: _It's ridiculous to make a dictionary of 100 lists to write to the JSON file right?_ Why do think so?

Comment: @moolenschot - no, you can easily create a hundred lists. That's small for modern computers. use a for loop or a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import json

with open('d.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump({f'{i}':[] for i in range(100,0,-1)}, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: `range(100,1,-1)` only goes to 2 (range is left closed, right open). Do `range(100,0,-1)`.